# BufferedReader directly to byte[]

Tags: java, sockets, arrays, inputstream, bufferedreader

is there any possibility my following BufferedReader is able to put the input directly into a byte[]?

```
public static Runnable reader() throws IOException {
    Log.e("Communication", "reader");
    din = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    brdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(din), 300);
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {
       try {
       char[] buffer = new char[200];
           int length = brdr.read(buffer, 0, 200);
           String message = new String(buffer, 0, length);
           btrar = message.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");                      
           int i=0;
           for (int counter = 0; counter < message.length(); counter++) {
              i++;  
              System.out.println(btrar[counter] + " = " + " btrar "  + i);
           }
    ...
```

thats the part of the reader, pls have a look.

I want the input directly to btrar,

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> is there any possibility my following BufferedReader is able to put the input directly into a byte[]?

Any `Reader` is designed to let you read *characters*, not bytes. To read binary data, just use an `InputStream` - using `BufferedInputStream` to buffer it if you want.

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but you can use something like:

```
BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
while (!done) {
    // TODO: Rename btrar to something more meaningful
    int bytesRead = input.read(btrar);
    // Do something with the data...
}
```

Comment: @Ekonion: Yes, using a `Reader` when you want binary data is wrong.

Comment: hmm.. dont seems to be what i want.. see, i want the `String message = new String(buffer, 0, length);` not as a string. This should be a byte[]. That is what i try to achieve

Comment: @Ekonion: Well the code I've given you is reading into `btrar`, which I assume is declared somewhere else, as a `byte[]`. It's not at all clear what you want compared with what I've given you...

Comment: if it is reading into `btrar`, what is `bytesRead` for? Maybe a mistelling of mine. The incomeing data should put into btrar.. the name *B*ytes*T*o*R*eceive*AR*ray comes therefrom.

Comment: @Ekonion: `bytesRead` indicates *how many* bytes have been read. (It may not fill the whole byte array.) I'd name the variable `incomingData` or something similar - it's fine that there's a meaning for `btrar`, but you couldn't possibly expect anyone else to understand that meaning from just the name.

Comment: omg... how many.. obvious.. xD sorry. I expected, you dont know the meaning, so i told you ^^

Comment: @Ekonion: My point is that a name should be meaningful *without* a separate explanation. But I'm glad the code has fixed your problem.

Comment: i will remember that and change names of "nothingsaying" vars to "selfexplaining" ^^

Comment: @JonSkeet - how about mixed data ? i want to read from socket stream which contains HTTP [RFC2616] header  and binary data as body (eg JPG file) ? so i have created a CRLFBytesReader  to read a header line by line and now i want to get rest of remaining bytes from  Reader  InputStream???

Comment: @ceph3us: I have no idea what you mean by "BOS of Reader", and it's not really clear what you're asking. Perhaps you should ask a new question. Your `CRLFBytesReader` would have to be careful to buffer any binary data *as* binary data though.

Comment: @ceph3us: No, you should ask a new question.