# buffered reader with special/escape characters to be made into string

Tags: java, encryption, escaping, special-characters, bufferedreader

I have a question regarding escape characters being passed onto bufferedreader.

i have a input which is gotten from a bufferedreader, for example,

```
bufferedreader input :  X: ^¤Z¯ùYåf~Nkì£#nØØ0{ö9.Y²úAâq3#hlÃÂûþÛàºAèuv\Õ4<¹1IÓâÛÛh2Âøkñ_øBÅîf½/`
ÕX§^¯ñ8ø[µ¾§rFXô?zþ4ÿLÁxf¹î

received input :  X: ^¤Z¯ùYåf~Nkì£#nØØ0{ö9.Y²úAâq3#hlÃÂûþÛàºAèuv\Õ4<¹1IÓâÛÛh2Âøkñ_øBÅîf½/`
```

**is there a way that i can read this in as a string of encrypted text, including all the special characters? i want buffered reader input and received input to have the same value always regardless of input's special characters**

It would be better if i do not have to use external utils.

what i have tried...read in client input stream to buffer reader

```
    String userInput;
    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketClient.getInputStream()));
    String gXmodP = "";

    userInput = unEscapeString(stdIn.readLine());
```

and

```
public static String unEscapeString(String s){
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    switch (s.charAt(i)){
        case '\n': sb.append("\\n"); break;

        // ... rest of escape characters
        default: sb.append(s.charAt(i));
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [BufferedReader directly to byte\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107104/bufferedreader-directly-to-byte)

Comment: This looks like binary data interpreted as text. Is this correct?

Comment: What i've done is to change a BigInteger to string, using a function to encrypt using String as input, and byte[] as output, i obtain a encrypted byte[] data. And do this String encrypted = new String(encryptedKey, "ISO-8859-1");

Comment: `BufferedReader` is for text. Encrypted data isn't text. Converting encrypted data into a String doesn't make sense, and neither does your question.

Comment: hmm what im trying to do here is to get my server to generate a BigInteger value, encrypt it and send it to client so that client can decrypt and get back the value. What method should i use then?